# Multi-line text dataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

tf.data.* has dataset classes.  There is a TextLineDataset, but what I need is one for multiline text (between start/end tokens). Is there a way to use a different line-break delimiter for tf.data.TextLineDataset?

I am an experienced developer, but a python neophyte. I can read but my writing is limited.  I am bending an existing Tensorflow NMT tutorial to my own dataset.  Most TFRecord tutorials involve jpgs or other structured data.

Comment: Try to post what you've done so far. It will help the community to answer you

Comment: I think you'll have to code your own Dataset subclass. If you're interested, the definition of the TextLineDataset class is at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/data/ops/readers.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two options:

1. Write a generator and then use `Dataset.from_generator`: In your generator you can read your file line by line, append to your example while doing that and then yield when you encounter your custom delimiter.
2. First parse your file, create `tf.train.SequenceExample` with multiple lines and then store your dataset as a `TFRecordDataset` (more cumbersome option in my opinion)